# How to protect the contact us page from spammers? Even using captcha, validation etc I sitll receive spam letters

Tags: spam, spam-prevention, security

I have on my site, every field validation + captcha protection + math validation + server scripting validation, but still this a spammer keeps sending me spam mails. Is there any better smarter protection protect those ugly face's?

special sites like: `http://mysite.com/contact.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably manual form spam and it's difficult to eliminate. There are some client side scripting solutions that might help get rid of some more automated and semi-automated spam but it sounds like you may have already tried them. The thing is that it's easy and cheap for someone to hire a person to enter this spam. Usually it can be done for about $5 for 100 or so form submissions. The spammer gives their 'employee' a list of sites and what to paste in and they go at it.

Client side timer scripts offer the best protection against manual cut-and-paste and other quick submission techniques. For example, a script that requires a visitor be on a page 1 minute before the submit button is activated.

Comment: Client-side scripts are also the easiest for spammers to bypass. It takes the same amount of time to implement a timer server-side, and there's no way for the spammer to bypass it if you do it correctly.

Comment: I agree, i think its the $5 buks issue. Someone is doing it actually.